# paymentQueue(_:updatedTransactions:) not called with non finished transactions

Tags: ios, storekit

We have backend validation for receipts, and we call `finishTransaction(transaction)` only after backend successfully validates a receipt.
For cases when something wrong happens between a purchase and a receipt validation, I expect `paymentQueue(_:updatedTransactions:)` to be called with a transaction that I can handle and extract a previous purchase.

- `paymentQueue(_:updatedTransactions:)` is called at a regular purchase
- `paymentQueue(_:updatedTransactions:)` is called for a restore case
- `paymentQueue(_:updatedTransactions:)` - is not called at app start/resume with a transaction that was not marked finished

Steps to reproduce:

- Initiate an inapp system popup
- Confirm a purchase when app is closed

Simplified code looks like:

```
   // Called in `application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` before Firebase and any libs initialization
   func initialize() {
      SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
      fetchProducts()
  }

    // SKPaymentTransactionObserver
    func paymentQueue(_: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
        transactions.forEach { transaction in
            switch transaction.transactionState {
            case .purchasing, .deferred:
                break
            case .purchased:
                uploadReceipt {
                    if case let .success(value) = $0 {
                        SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
                    }
                }
            case .failed:
                SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
            case .restored:
                SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
            @unknown default:
                break
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

Any advices?

Comment: It shouldn't matter, but why are you calling `finishTransaction` on `SKPaymentQueue.default()` rather than the queue that was passed to the delegate function?

Comment: @Paulw11 I double checked and changing SKPaymentQueue.default() on the queue that was passed to the delegate function DOES work. Quite strange bit it fixes the problem. Thank you for pointing on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call`finishTransaction` on the `SKPaymentQueue` that is passed to the delegate method instead of using `SKPaymentQueue.default()`